# How do I rotate the pictures of my iPhone/iPad wallpaper every few minutes?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore

I want the wallpaper on my iPhone/iPad to rotate/change to a new wallpaper every few minutes, so that I won't get bored seeing the same picture over and over again every time I'm on my phone.

Are there any **free** iPhone apps which allow me to do so?

Comment: Is your iPhone/iPad jailbroken by any chance? That would change the situation and some workarounds would be possible then.

Comment: @bart how can it be done assuming my iphone is jailbroken ?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.  First Jailbreak your iDevice.  Then once your device is jailbroken look up winterboard.  install winterboard and find tweak option for changing wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to change the wallpaper at a set amount of time. It has to be done manually.

I'm pretty sure this is to save battery life.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You will have to do it manually.